# ImportError: No module named Games.Table

Tags: python-2.7

I recently got this error: ImportError: No module named Games.Table

I'm using Python2.7, any idea of how can I install this module? I already tried using pip install Games.Table but all I get is "ERROR: No matching distribution found for Games.Table" and "ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Games.Table (from versions: none)" If someone is able to help me out please let me know, thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  What module is this ```Games``` module?  Does it support python 2.7?

Comment: Thank you! And I get this:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Login.py", line 1, in <module>
    from Houdini.HoudiniFactory import HoudiniFactory
  File "/var/oasis/Houdini/HoudiniFactory.py", line 18, in <module>
    from Houdini.Crumbs import retrieveItemCollection, retrieveRoomCollection, \
  File "/var/oasis/Houdini/Crumbs/__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
    from Houdini.Crumbs.Room import RoomSchema, RoomCollection
  File "/var/oasis/Houdini/Crumbs/Room.py", line 6, in <module>
    from Houdini.Handlers.Games.Table import leaveTable

Comment: And at the end of that (I wasn't able to add it bcs of the characters limit) I get the "ImportError: No module named Games.Table"

Comment: Please include the information in your post and not in the comments.